# Why is my program returning an infinite loop?

Tags: c, linked-list, nodes, infinite-loop

I'm programming in C to basically add a node into a linked list and then it is suppose to sort it. The node contains a string, a count, and a pointer to the next node. When you add a new node, it goes through and checks to make sure there isn't a node with that string already in it. If there is, it does not add a new node but instead adds 1 to the count. Then it is suppose to sort it in decreasing order.

Here is my code for the add function.

```
void ins(char s[])
{
    NODE_T *temp = (NODE_T*)malloc(sizeof(NODE_T));
    strcpy(temp->symbol, s);
    NODE_T *loop = (NODE_T*)malloc(sizeof(NODE_T));
    NODE_T *countCheck = (NODE_T*)malloc(sizeof(NODE_T));

    if(head == NULL)
    {
        head = temp;
        head->count = 1;
        head->next = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        loop = head;
        while(loop != NULL)
        {
            if(strcmp(temp->symbol, loop->symbol) == 0)
            {
                loop->count++;
                countCheck = head;
                while(countCheck != NULL)
                {
                    if(loop->count > head->count)
                    {
                        loop->next = head;
                        head = loop;
                        break;
                    }
                    countCheck = countCheck->next;
                }
                break;
            }
            else if(loop->next == NULL)
            {
                temp->count = 1;
                loop->next = temp;
                temp->next = NULL;
                break;
            }
            else
                loop = loop->next;
        }
    }
}
```

So far I've only added a way to sort if the current node, temp, is greater than the first node. It sorts correctly, but when I call the print function it prints it in an infinite loop.

Below are my codes for declaring the node, the print function, and my main.

```
typedef struct NODE
{
    char symbol[10];
    int count;
    struct NODE *next;
} NODE_T;

NODE_T *head = NULL;

void prl()
{
    NODE_T *temp  = (NODE_T*)malloc(sizeof(NODE_T));
    temp = head;
    while(temp != NULL)
    {
        printf("%s %d\n", temp->symbol, temp->count);
        temp = temp->next;
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    char command[3];
    char string[10];
    printf("Command: "); fflush(stdout);
    scanf("%s", &command);
    while(strcmp(command, "end") != 0)
    {
        if(strcmp(command, "ins") == 0)
        {
            scanf("%s", &string);
            ins(string);
        }
        else if(strcmp(command, "prl") == 0)
        {
            prl();
        }
        printf("Command: "); fflush(stdout);
        scanf("%s", &command);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

To use the main, type 'ins apple' when it asks for a Command and it'll add apple with a count of 1 as a node. If you add apple again, it'll increment the the node by 1 only. Adding banana 3 times will make banana the first node but when I call the print function, prl, it prints 
banana 3
apple 2
in an infinite loop.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `NODE_T *temp  = (NODE_T*)malloc(sizeof(NODE_T));
    temp = head;` leaks memory for absolutely no discernible reason. This appears to be something of a pattern in your code. I'd advise starting with the absolute basics of C.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-prgrams/).

Comment: Look at your countCheck loop - what happens to the node that was pointing to the node you are moving to the head? And, what happens to the old loop->next node when you move it to the head? Fixing these two issues properly will fix your infinite loop problem.

Comment: Don't cast the result of `malloc()` - the cast is unnecessary and will also hide the warning if you mistakenly omit the prototype for the function.

Comment: `char command[3];` --> `char command[4];`